# ¿Por qué me muestra error 500 al subir mi sitio codeingiter en Bluehost?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting

Me da un error 500 al subir mi sitio de **codeingiter** a Bluehost, lo menciono porque en Siteground no tuve problemas al subirlo, este es mi .htaccess

```
#write your project folder name as rewritebase
RewriteBase /educativo/cole/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?/$1 [L]
```

no logro, hacer que funcione.

Comment: Revisa el log para ver a que es debido el error

Comment: cambiaste los datos necesarios en tu **application/config/** `config.php => base_url`, `database.php => array_config`